# optimize the code that iterates only the desired combinations of elements from a table (list)

Tags: python-3.x, list

The program checks the kinship of horses.  I don't need to iterate through all possible combinations of rows from an existing table (a list of horse id numbers).

1. A child cannot be his own parent.
2. If for a given child, two id-horses from the list have already been indicated as Parent1/2, there is no need to repeat this combination and swap parents 1/2

In a program, extra combinations of id-horses significantly increase the program execution time. I need to reduce the number of combinations to a minimum

I must provide all the rows in the option: child and parents as input to the (def search_for_parents).
Here is an example table:

```
df = [10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Here is the required result of possible combinations obtained from the list:

```
№Comb; child; parent1; parent2;  
0;     10;     11;       12;  
1;     10;     11;       13;  
2;     10;     12;       13;  
3;     11;     10;       12;  
4;     11;     10;       13;  
5;     11;     12;       13;  
...  
9;     13;     10;       11;  
10;    13;     10;       12;  
11;    13;     11;       12;
```

My code:

```
    for child in range(len(df)):
        for parent1 in range(len(df)):
            for parent2 range(len(df)):
                if child != parent1 and child != parent2:
                    if  parent1 != parent2:
                            answ = search_for_parents(child, parent1, parent2)
```

but the current data enumeration code makes it so that the same data is received as input twice.
How can I optimize the code that takes data from a table?

Comment: This code allows you to get the required combinations at the input to the functions. But it adds two additional lists. Which slow down code execution if there are more than several hundred horses in the table.
'''

Comment: '''
combinations = []
for child in range(len(df)):
    for parent1 in range(len(df)):
        for parent2 in range(parent1 + 1, len(df)): 
            if child != parent1 and child != parent2:
                combination = (df[child], df[parent1], df[parent2])
                reversed_combination = (df[child], df[parent2], df[parent1])
                if combination not in combinations and reversed_combination not in combinations:
                    combinations.append(combination)
                    answ = search_for_parents(combination[0], combination[1], combination[2])
'''

Comment: Perhaps what is needed here is not combinations, but permutations
itertools.permutations
Or
  I would build a graph where the vertex is a horse and the edge A->B means that A is the child of B
Then your solution will not be generating all placements, but simply depth-first traversal of the graph

Comment: 5 levels of nesting = red flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from itertools import combinations


def get_comb(arr):
    for v in arr:
        for c in combinations((a for a in arr if a != v), 2):
            yield v, *c


for no, c in enumerate(get_comb([10, 11, 12, 13])):
    print(no, c)
```

Prints:

```
0 (10, 11, 12)
1 (10, 11, 13)
2 (10, 12, 13)
3 (11, 10, 12)
4 (11, 10, 13)
5 (11, 12, 13)
6 (12, 10, 11)
7 (12, 10, 13)
8 (12, 11, 13)
9 (13, 10, 11)
10 (13, 10, 12)
11 (13, 11, 12)
```

Comment: Yes! It's working. Thankyou! But Those same issues. This slows down code execution if there are more than a few hundred horses in the table.

Comment: @ViacheslavGrachev Profile your code, to make sure what part of the code is the slowest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once, and change this according to your code

```
import itertools

df = [10, 11, 12, 13]

for i, (child, (parent1, parent2)) in enumerate(itertools.product(df, itertools.combinations(df, 2))):
    if child != parent1 and child != parent2:
        print(child, parent1, parent2)
```

```
Output: 

10 11 12
10 11 13
10 12 13
11 10 12
11 10 13
11 12 13
12 10 11
12 10 13
12 11 13
13 10 11
13 10 12
13 11 12
```